# Why must a group with presentation $\langle r,s \mid r^n=s^2=1,rs=sr^{-1}\rangle$ have exactly $2n$ elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, dihedral-groups

In Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra*, they state on page 27 of chapter 1 that any group with the presentation $\langle r,s \mid r^n=s^2=1,rs=sr^{-1}\rangle$ must have exactly $2n$ elements. Why is this the case? If $G$ is the trivial group $\{1\}$, then it is surely the case that $1^n=1^2=1$ and $1\cdot 1=1\cdot 1^{-1}$, and $G$ is generated by $\{1\}$. It seems that I am misunderstanding how group presentations are defined, but I don't exactly know where my confusion lies.

Comment: It's a presentation of the dihedral group  of $2n$ elements.

Answer (score 4):

A group with presentation $\langle a_1,\dots,a_n\,|\, r_1,\dots,r_m\rangle$ is not just *any* group generated by elements $a_1,\dots,a_n$ which satisfy the relations $r_1,\dots,r_m$. It is the *most general* group satisfying those, in the sense that any group which satisfies those conditions is a quotient of that group. It is actually unique up to isomorphism.

You can either characterize it by this so-called *universal property*, or you can define it more prosaically as the quotient of the free group $F_n$ on the $n$ elements $a_1,\dots,a_n$ by the normalization of the subgroup generated by the relations $r_1,\dots,r_m$. (This construction gives a unique representative in the isomorphism class).

It is true that the trivial group satisfies any presentation (since it satisfies trivially any relation), and therefore it is (obviously) a quotient of the group actually given by the presentation.

Comment: I think it might be more accurate to describe it as the maximal group satisfying the conditions rather than the minimal group.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that my definition of group presentaiton was incomplete. Unfortunately, since Dummit and Foote have not introduced quotient groups at this point in the book, I do not fully understand this answer. (At this point in the book the idea of a group presentation has only been dealt with informally.) However, having reread the book, I think I worked out what I'm missing: for $G$ to have the presentation $\langle a_1,\dots,a_n\mid R_1,\dots,R_m \rangle$, it needs to be the case that...

Comment: 1. $G$ is generated by $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$.
 2. Each relation
    $R_1,\dots,R_m$ holds for $G$, where a relation is an equation in
    elements of $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}\cup\{1\}$.
 3. Any relation among the
    elements of $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ can be deduced from the above relations.

Comment: In the case of $G=\{1\}$, it is clearly the case that (1) and (2) hold. However, there are relations about $\{1\}$ that cannot be deduced from the relations $r^n=s^2=1$ and $rs=sr^{-1}$. For example, $1^3=1$, but this cannot be deduced from $r^n=s^2=1$ and $rs=sr^{-1}$, as there are groups for which it is not true that $r^3=1$ but *are* generated by $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ and satisfy $R_1,\dots,R_m$. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Joe Yes, that is a way to see it. And one of these groups is precisely the group with the given presentation (but at this point the definitions start to eat their own tails).

Comment: @CaptainLama: Thank you. I have one more question, if you don't mind: in Dummit and Foote, it says that the third condition that a presentation must satisfy is that any relation among the elements of $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ can be deduced from the relations given in the presentation. However, should it actually be that any relation among the elements of $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}\cup\{1\}$ can be deduced from the relations given in the presentation (that is, do we include the identity or not)?

Answer (score 0):

A general element of the group has the form $r^is^j$ with $0\leq i\leq n-1$ and $s=0,1$, by the two relations. Thus the group has $2n$ elements.